# SwiftUI-How to transition between text when a button is pressed

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I am making an exercise app and I want to transition between different exercises without making many seperate views as I am also making a timer which will publish too many times if I did that. I want to make it so that when I click a button, it will transition all the text from exercise1 to exercise 2 then to exercise 3 and so on. I want to transition all these using the same button.

So far what I have done is created navigation paths to different views that contain the different exercises but the timer broke when I did that because I called it many times causing it to countdown too fast. I want to see if I can contain all the exercises inside 1 view and transition between them. So for example I want to transition from:

```
Text(exercisePlan.exercise.title) to Text(exercisePlan.exercise2.title) then to Text(exercisePlan.exercise3.title) all with a click of one button
```

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ExerciseScreenView: View {
    @Binding var streaks: Streaks
    @Binding var timerStruct: TimerStruct
    var countdownTimer = 300
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var exercisePlan: ExercisePlan
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    func reset() {
        timerStruct.countdownTimer = 300
        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("1st Exercise (Scroll down for exercise steps)")) {
                    Text(exercisePlan.exercise.title)
                        .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .medium))
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Video example")) {
                    VideoPlayer(player: exercisePlan.exercise.video)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                }
                    Section(header: Text("Steps:")){
                        Text(exercisePlan.exercise.steps)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
                         
                    
                    
                    
            TimerView(streaks: $streaks, timerStruct: $timerStruct)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 15, trailing: 0))
                    
                    Button {
                        navigationPath.append("ExerciseScreen2View")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Next exercise")
                            .padding()
                            .background((Color(red: 184/255, green: 243/255, blue: 255/255)))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create an array of the `Exercises`. Pressing the button should increase an index to get the relevant plan to show in your view.

Small code example:

```
struct ExerciseScreenView: View {
    
    var exercises: [Exercise]
    @State var index: 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(exercises[index].title)
            Button {
                    if exercisePlan.count - 1 > index {
                        index += 1                        
                    } else {
                        // leave screen
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Next exercise")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example and can be improved by a lot, but it gives you a basic idea how to do it.

Comment: whenever I do that it tells me that the type has no subscripts

Comment: I updated the answer. I took the wrong object, it should be an array of exercises.